# With logstash and grok, how can I split TIME into hour, minute and second?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a field that can look like this: `23:59:47`

I tried using
`%{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second}` as a pattern, but that gives me the generic `grokparsefailure`.

{TIME:time} works well, but I want hour, minute and second.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {"message" => "%{DATE:date} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the full grok filter please ?

Comment: Yes, I most certainly can do that.

Comment: Tried 23:59:47 and  %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} at  https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and it works. Can you put in the complete line with the date that you are trying to parse

Comment: Using http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ with 23:59:57 as input and %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} as filter. I do retrieve each field separatly.

But if I use your complete filter, then there's no match. Can you as well provide a full line as input please ?

Comment: The problem may occur because you're trying to parse a date AND a time and I think the time may be included in the first date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is quite an old question, but I just had the same query and TIME seems to work now.

Using https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ with 23:59:57 as input and %{TIME:timestamp} as filter gives me the original plus separate fields for HOUR, MINUTE and SECOND